# How to parse XMI?

Tags: .net, parsing, xmi

I need a software to parse XMI documents. .NET should be able to process the output. Please inform me about useful related softwares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps feed the xmi [xsd](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20071001/07-10-06.xsd) into xsd.exe, and use the resultant model with XmlSerializer? job done?

Comment: I want to read a XMI document and recognize classes and attributes and export them. These information will be used for generating C# code!

Comment: @Arash - but it is just xml... load it into a DOM and work from there... to be honest, I'm unclear where the problem starts...

Comment: @Mark - let me clarify the problem. I want to design a code generator. This code generator takes a model (for example UML model) in a XMI file. The first step is extracting important information like classes and attributes and keep them in a suit format to be used in .NET. Now, I need a program to do this job and also a "template-based code generator" to compile my information considering it's template.

Comment: @Arash - *personally*, I would (and indeed, have - not xmi, but similar) write the entire thing in xslt then; but... where lies the problem? either deserialize it into an object model based on the xsd, or load it into a DOM...?

Comment: @Mark - thank you very much for your clues. I should learn more about DOM and xslt.